# Gerunds and Participles in compound Adjective

Tags: gerunds, participles

1. 'English-**speaking** countries'
2. 'Time-**saving** gadgets'
3. 'Mouth-**watering** food'
4. 'Good-**looking** girl'

English-speaking, time-saving, mouth-watering and good-looking are adjectives here. But how are these words 'speaking', 'saving', 'watering' and 'looking' working?

Are they verbal nouns or verbal adjectives?

Comment: The participle of the verb works as a part of the compound adjective - that's all.

Comment: No, not nouns or adjectives, but gerund-participle verbs functioning as heads of the compound adjectives.

Answer (score 2):

They are present participles part of a compound adjective. The fact that the adjective is compound as you say, it doesn't make it less of an adjective:

> ***running*** water *means* water ***that runs***
> ***flourishing*** business *means* business that ***flourishes***
> ***English-speaking*** countries *means* countries ***that speak English***.

[GrammarMonster](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/present_participle.htm) says:

> ***A present participle*** is a word that (1) ends "-ing," (2) is formed
> from a verb, and (3) ***is used as an adjective*** or to form verb tense.

In combination with a noun or adjective, present participles form compound adjectives:

> A compound adjective is an adjective that contains two or more words.
>
> In general we put a hyphen between two or more words (before a noun)
> when we want them to act as a single idea (adjective) that describes something.
>
> - I live in an ***English-speaking*** country.
>
> *English-speaking* is an ***adjective*** (used to describe the country). *We
> use a hyphen to connect the word **English** with **speaking** to show that it
> is one adjective (or one idea)*.
> ([Grammar.cl](https://www.grammar.cl/english/compound-adjectives.htm))

So all these are ***verbal adjectives***, and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attributive_verb) draws attention to a distinction between ***verbal*** and ***deverbal*** adjectives:

> In English (and in most European languages), verb forms that can be used attributively are typically non-finite forms — participles and infinitives — as well as certain *verb-derived words that function as ordinary adjectives*. All words of these types may be called ***verbal adjectives***, although those of the latter type (those that *behave grammatically like ordinary adjectives, with no verb-like features*) may be distinguished as ***deverbal adjectives***.
>
> An example of a ***verbal adjective*** with *verb-like features* is the word ***wearing*** in the sentence
>
> - The man ***wearing*** a hat is my father (*it behaves as a verb in ***taking an object***, a hat*, although the resulting phrase ***wearing a hat*** *functions like an attributive adjective in modifying **man***).
>
> An example of a ***deverbal adjective*** is the word ***interesting*** in
>
> - That was a very ***interesting*** speech; although it is derived from the verb ***to interest***, i*t behaves here entirely like an ordinary adjective such as ***nice*** or ***long****.

Comment: Burning House- House which is burning (Present participle Adjective shows Continuation). running horse- Horse which is running. Can we say here, house that burns and horse that runs?     In reducing a relative clause, we generally use participle clause. Ex-The man who lives near my house walks to work every day. We reduce it to 'The man living near my house walks to work everyday'.  In this case I can understand using 'water that runs' and 'business that flourishes'.    A/c to my understanding 'English-speaking countries' means ' countries that are speaking English'. It seems wrong tho.

Comment: @RADS No: in "burning house" and "running horse", "burning" and "running" are verbs functioning as attributive modifiers.